# Rails validations, if conditions and actions in the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my model I need a validation with an if condition and an action name (only update). It should be like:

```
validates email, :presence => {with:true}, :if => condition || :on => :update
```

But it gives me a syntax error. I am using rails 3.2.11 with ruby 1.9.3. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Rails Custom Validators](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators)

```
validates_with CustomValidator, :on => :create
```

and have a separate CustomValidator class

```
class CustomValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if condition
      record.email.present?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh thanks man. present? method is excellent! It is a cure for me